# Django file upload (get file DATA, not just filepath)

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to upload an admin Django form to gcloud. My gcloud part works, but requires a filepath. I would like to access the raw data of the file from a form upload and provide that to gcloud's `blob` upload.

I have a model that looks like this

```
from django.db import models
from gcloud import storage
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# Create your models here.
class TestFile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64,
        # NOT NULL, UNIQUE, no default.
        null=False, default=None, blank=False, unique=True
    )
    data = models.FileField()
    img_src = models.CharField(max_length=255,
        null=True, default=None, blank=True
    )
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestFile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        filename = self.data.url
        print("FILENAME: " + filename)
        # How do I get the file DATA
```

I also have an admin table like so.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

from .models import TestFile

class TestFileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ( 
                "data",
                "name",
                "_img_src",
        )   
        def _img_src(self, obj):
                return mark_safe(u'<img style="height: 75px;width: 75px;object-fit: cover;" src="%s"/>' % obj.img_src)
admin.site.register(TestFile, TestFileAdmin)
```

Using whatever storage back-end I want, I have some example code like this:

```
from gcloud import storage
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import os

credentials_dict = { 
        "type": "service_account",
        "client_id": os.environ["BACKUP_CLIENT_ID"],
        "client_email": os.environ["BACKUP_CLIENT_EMAIL"],
        "private_key_id": os.environ["BACKUP_PRIVATE_KEY_ID"],
        "private_key": os.environ["BACKUP_PRIVATE_KEY"],
}

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(
        credentials_dict
)
client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials, project="aerobic-copilot-232607")
bucket = client.get_bucket("tgtree")
blob = bucket.blob("temp.png")
blob.upload_from_filename("./temp.png")
# How to I upload from DATA?
url = blob.public_url
print(url)
```

**Questions:**

How do I intercept the `save()` function and get the actual bytes of data from `self.data`?

Once this is done, what's the blob function to pipe that into the `blob.upload`?

If python weren't dynamically typed, it would be a breeze to see what fits where, but it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get the data as **`self.data.read()`**

example :

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TestFile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    filename = self.data.url
    print("FILENAME: " + filename)
    data_in_bytes = self.data.read()
```

**Ref** : [**`class FieldFile`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile)